# C - compare read in float to zero

Tags: c

In my programm I have several float variables that I need to compare to 0. Those variables are being read in through printf.

```
float a;
scanf("%f", &a);
if (a=0)
{
printf("a is zero");
return 0;
}
```

But it doesn't work when I give in a 0 through scanf. "a is zero" isn't displayed. It doesn't work with (a=0.0) and doesnt work with (a=0.0f) or (a=0.). The only way I managed to do it is with (0 < a && a < 0.0000000000001)

but I feel like this is not a very good way to do it.

What did I do wrong? Why doesn't it recognize the 0 I input in with scanf as 0?

Comment: Please read this http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Don't ignore compiler warnings, they are telling you what is wrong with your program.

Comment: euh you probably mean `if (a==0)`

Comment: if `a = 0` is not an error, edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: a = 0 is not an error!                                                     the compiler doesnt give out any warnings or errors                       but I changed = to == and it works now!

Comment: if `a = 0` is not an error than all your condition equals to 0 and compiler just throw away if-block.

Comment: `if(a=0)` means `if(0)` means the `if` is never executed. Warnings should be treated as errors.

Comment: @Kevin GCC(mingw32) will report neither errors nor warnings by default. If something do like this `if(CONSTANT=VARIABLE)`, it will always return `TRUE`, in other words, it'll always run `if statement`.

Comment: @JIghtuse Where specifically on this website is the answer to this question?

Comment: @mbratch You certainly can use `==` to compare floating-point numbers. I do it all the time.

Comment: @PascalCuoq yes I'm sure it can work in some cases. In this particular problem, I completely skated past the single `=` issue, so it's irrelevant to this particular problem.

Comment: @PascalCuoq you can do many things in C: ignore undefined behaviour, compare floating-point numbers by `==`. No one can guarantee this will be working, because doing so you ignore standards.

Comment: @JIghtuse Yes, you are totally right, comparing a floating-point number to zero with a C compiler that specifies IEEE 754 is akin to invoking undefined behavior. Same thing.

Comment: @PascalCuoq I didn't say that, it is defects of different kind. If you really need direct link, take it: http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison . But I encorage you to read Basic questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change "=" to "==". You can write "if" statement to following style:

```
if (CONSTANT == variable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the assignment operator(=) to Comaparison Operator (==) in if Condition.

In addition to that do type casting while comparing the value

```
if (a==(float)0)
```

Comment: do like this: `if (a == 0.0)` will be better, just in my opinion. :)

Comment: @kvd Ya thats too fine